# Module signature mismatch when constraint says types should match

Tags: types, module, ocaml

Consider the below code:

```ml
module A = struct
  module type ZType = sig
    type z
  end
end

module B = struct
  module M (InputZ : A.ZType) = struct
    module OutputZ = InputZ
  end
end

module C = struct
  module type CZType = sig
    type z = { s : int }
  end

  module M (Z1 : CZType) = struct
    module B1 = B.M(Z1)
    module Z2 : A.ZType with type z = Z1.z = B1.OutputZ
    module Z3 : CZType = Z2 (* This line gives a signature mismatch error *)
  end
end
```

As you can see, `C.CZType` is a more specific version of `A.ZType`, the only difference being that `C.CZType.z` has been specified as a record type.

I would have thought the following chain of inferences would have allowed this code to type check:

1. `Z2.z` is the same as `Z1.z` (due to the signature constraint `with type z = Z1.z`)
2. `Z1` is of type `CZType`
3. Therefore, `Z2.z` is the record `{ s : int }`
4. Therefore, `Z3` is of type `CZType`.

But this does not work. Instead, the compiler complains:

```
Signature mismatch:
Modules do not match: sig type z = Z1.z end is not included in CZType
Type declarations do not match:
  type z = Z1.z
is not included in
  type z = { s : int; }
Their kinds differ.
```

How can I convince the compiler that `B1.OutputZ` is of type `CZType`?

---

Andreas Rossberg correctly identified the problem. The tricky part is that, in my case `B` doesn't "know" about `C`, so it can't constrain `OutputZ.z` to have the right kind.

To solve that, I tried further parameterizing `B` over the desired output module type:

```ml
module A = struct
  module type ZType = sig
    type z
  end
end

module type TypeModType = sig
  (* It is seemingly not possible to constrain T to be a subtype of A.ZType *)
  module type T
end

module B = struct
  module M (TypeMod : TypeModType) = struct
    module M (InputZ : TypeMod.T) = struct
      module OutputZ = InputZ
      type z = InputZ.z (* Now this line gives an error *)
    end
  end
end

module C = struct
  module type CZType = sig
    type z = { s : int }
  end

  module M (Z1 : CZType) = struct
    module B1 = B.M(struct module type T = CZType end)
    module B2 = B1.M(Z1)
    (* This line is now fine thanks to extra parameterization *)
    module Z2: CZType = B2.OutputZ
  end
end
```

Of course, the problem now is that it is not possible to constrain the space of module types that `B` is parameterized over: it's either all or none.

---

**Update**

Thank you, the responses have been very helpful. Using Andreas Rossberg's observation that OCaml sees that type *identity* is preserved but not type *kind*, all that is needed to fix it is to externally define a type of the appropriate kind. Below is a motivating example:

```
module type Graph = sig
  type id
  type attrs
  type node = {
    neighbors : id list;
    attrs : attrs
  }
end

type point = { x: int; y: int }

module type LocatedGraph = sig
  type id
  type attrs = point
  type node = {
    neighbors : id list;
    attrs : attrs
  }
end

module AugmentedGraph (OrigGraph : Graph) = struct
  type id = Orig of OrigGraph.id | Added of int
  type attrs = OrigGraph.attrs
  type node = {
    neighbors : id list;
    attrs : attrs
  }
end

module IntLocatedGraph = struct
  type id = int
  type attrs = point
  type node = {
    neighbors : id list;
    attrs : attrs
  }
end

module AugmentedIntLocatedGraph = AugmentedGraph(IntLocatedGraph)
module AugmentedIntLocatedGraphIsLocatedGraph : LocatedGraph = AugmentedIntLocatedGraph
```

This achieves three properties simultaneously:

1. **Parametricity**: If `AugmentedGraph` is given a `LocatedGraph`, the result is a `LocatedGraph`.
2. **Constraining functor argument types**: `AugmentedGraph` can only be applied to a `Graph` or its subtypes.
3. **Encapsulation**: `AugmentedGraph` does not need to know about `LocatedGraph` in order to produce a `LocatedGraph`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, the root issue is that the functor

```ml
module M (InputZ : A.ZType) = struct
  module OutputZ = InputZ
end
```

creates a copy of the `InputZ` module restricted to the `A.ZType` module type completely independent of the original module `InputZ`.
In particular, this means that all extra-information is lost.
Such functors that makes restricted copy of their arguments are currently an anti-pattern with OCaml (which at some point will be resolved by transparent ascriptions).

And indeed, if we remove this copy from your code (and fix the module type constraint on `Z2`), we remove the type error:

```ml
module B = struct
  module M (InputZ : A.ZType) = struct
  end
end
module M (Z1 : CZType) = struct
 module B = B(Z1)
 module Z2 : sig type z = Z1.z = { s : int} end = Z1
 module Z3 : CZType = Z2 (* we didn't lose any information, and thus this works *)
end
```

Moreover, avoiding the functor argument copy also protects you from running into troubles with applicative functors in the future. In particular, for any applicative functor `F`, with your implementation `F(B(Z1).OutputZ)` ≠ `F(Z1)` which is probably not the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The simpler version of this is:

```
module A = struct type t = {a : int} end
module B : sig type t = A.t end = A
module C : sig type t = {a : int} end = B;;

Error: Signature mismatch:
       Modules do not match:
         sig type t = A.t end
       is not included in
         sig type t = { a : int; } end
       Type declarations do not match:
         type t = A.t
       is not included in
         type t = { a : int; }
       Their kinds differ.
```

The problem is that propagating the *identity* of a record or data type does not propagate its *representation* (or "kind", as OCaml calls it here). In fact, the signature annotation on `B` *hides* that representation. To keep it transparent, you need to write:

```
module A = struct type t = {a : int} end
module B : sig type t = A.t = {a : int} end = A
module C : sig type t = {a : int} end = B
```

The inferred signatures also show this:

```
module A : sig type t = { a : int; } end
module B : sig type t = A.t = { a : int; } end
module C : sig type t = { a : int; } end
```

Now, applying this observation to your example is a bit more work and I leave it as an exercise. :)